# Help calculating tax and discounts

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm having problems correctly calculating tax and discounts per item, mainly because I'm not certain what the order should be. I can do this on a calculator without any problems but writing the SQL is a different story. The total column was done by a friend and works as expected. Based on his total column, I've added the taxtotal column which seems to give the correct result. I am still having an issue with the discounts though.

There are 2 discount columns. One is an initial discount that can be set in the inventory and a second discount that can be applied by the clerk. The columns for the discounts are `op.discount` and `p.discount`. There is no separate table for discounts and are just columns within the two joins.

I'd like to make sure that my taxtotal column is correct as well so if someone sees an issue or a better way of writing it, I'd be appreciative of any suggestions.

```
SELECT
    p.tax_state as tax_state,
    p.tax_fed as tax_fed,
    p.price AS price,
    op.quantity AS quantity,
    op.discount AS discount,
    (p.tax_state + p.tax_fed) AS tax,
    ( ( p.tax_state + p.tax_fed ) / 100 ) * ( p.price * op.quantity - ( p.price * op.quantity * op.discount + p.discount /100 ) ) AS taxtotal,
    (p.price * (1 + ((p.tax_state + p.tax_fed) / 100)) * (1.0 - op.discount) * op.quantity) AS total
FROM pos_order o
JOIN pos_item_order op ON op.order_id = o.order_id
JOIN inv_item p ON p.item_id = op.item_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can create function do this

```
SELECT
    p.tax_state as tax_state,
    p.tax_fed as tax_fed,
    p.price AS price,
    op.quantity AS quantity,
    op.discount AS discount,
    (p.tax_state + p.tax_fed) AS tax,
    taxtotal(p.tax_state , p.tax_fed, p.price ,op.quantity, op.discount ) AS taxtotal
    valueTotal(p.tax_state , p.tax_fed, p.price ,op.quantity, op.discount ) AS total
FROM pos_item_order op 
JOIN inv_item p ON p.item_id = op.item_id
```

create this function

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `taxtotal`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `taxtotal`(`tax_state` double,`tax_fed` double,`price` double,`quantity` INT,`discount` double) RETURNS double
BEGIN
    RETURN ( ( `tax_state` + `tax_fed`) / 100 ) * ( `price` * `quantity` - ( `price` * `quantity` * `discount`/100 ) );
END
;;
DELIMITER ;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `valueTotal`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `valueTotal`(`tax_state` double,`tax_fed` double,`price` double,`quantity` INT,`discount` double) RETURNS double
BEGIN
    RETURN (p.price * (1 + ((p.tax_state + p.tax_fed) / 100)) * (1.0 - op.discount) * op.quantity);
END
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: i test it . it work correctly .you just one time create this function and always can use this function

Comment: Hi Amir. Thanks for the function. For some reason, I can't get it to load. I get a syntax error on line 3 for some reason.

Comment: Amir, would you please help me with the discount? I'm not sure of how to write this.

Comment: what is the type of discount column

Comment: if its decimal when you try ( p.price * op.quantity * ((op.discount + p.discount) / 100 )) with value for example : select ( 1000 * 1 * ((1 + 1) / 100 )) it work curectly it return 20 mean 2% of 1000

Comment: OK Amir, thank you. I'll try and work with what you've given me here. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```
( p.price * op.quantity * ((op.discount + p.discount) / 100 ))
```

with extra braces because [multiply has a higher precedence than add](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) - assuming these are both percentage discounts?

Comment: Hi Rup, thanks. The values for the discounts are stored in decimal format: .5 I'll give this a try now. thanks.

Comment: Ah, OK - you probably don't want the `/100` here then. But maybe I've misunderstood. (If they're absolute discounts i.e. .5 means 50 cents not 50% then I've misunderstood!)

Comment: Rup, I'm not certain of the output is correct or not. Here is what I have. I have an initial discount of .1 and an applied discount of .1 totaling .2 or 2% of $9.99. What your code returns is 0.021. Is this correct?

Comment: OK, running your code without the `/100` now gives me 2.1. I assume rounded would give me 2, correct?

Comment: It shouldn't - I've copied you adding not compounding the discounts. Or should it be compounded? I'm not sure. You should talk to your business people about what the expected answers should be, though.

Comment: Yeah, Rup, I don't think the output is correct. What they need are these two discounts shown on the receipt. This is just the total, in dollars that was taken off of all items. Before I can get that total though, I need to get each item discount first then I can group by orderId and SUM